# How to implement nested incremental loop in python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

I have some logic in java script from which i need to implement in python,

As like we have classic for loop with three parameters, initialization, condition and increment,

js sample code :

```
for(let i=0; i< waypoints.length; i++) {
    const wayPoints_status = [];
    if(a == condition) {
            if(i==0) {
                wayPoints_status[0].push({id: waypoints[0].id, status: 'executing'});
                for(var j=1;j< waypoints.length; j++){
                    wayPoints_status.push({id:waypoints[j].id, 'status': 'pending'});
                }
                return wayPoints_status
            }
    }
    setTimeInterval(function(){
        if(a == condition) {
            if(i>0 && waypoints_status.length>0) {
                for(var k=0; k<waypoints_status.length; k++) {
                    if(wayPoints_status[k].status == 'executing') {
                        let charCheck = k;
                        wayPoints_status[charCheck].status =  'completed';
                        wayPoints_status[charCheck+1].status = 'executing';
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
    
    },1000)
}
```

I have tried below code in python

```
 waypoints_data = self.waypoints

        waypoint_status_list = []
        for index, value in enumerate(waypoints_data):
            # if (self.mission_status_from_ui == MESSAGE_CONSTANTS["mission_status"]["EXECUTING"]):
            self.logger.debug(index)
            self.logger.debug(value)
            if (index == 0):
                waypoint_status={
                    "id": value["id"],
                    "status": "executing"
                }
                waypoint_status_list.append(waypoint_status)

                self.logger.debug(waypoint_status_list)
```

How to increment i value, and how to add nested loop which is j  and k in incremental way.

The quick help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is the JavaScript example running in a browser or on a server?

Comment: What is the intent of this code? Do you want to just loop though the statuses and update them to executing/completed as needed but in an async manner?

Comment: @yunzen it is executing on server side

Comment: @JonSG yes based on the status , i need to update the statuses of each waypoints after 10 seconds of delay

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update the statuses then you can:

```
import random
import time

def update_waypoint_statuses(waypoint_statuses):
    prior_waypoint_status = {"id": None, "status": None}

    for current_waypoint_status in waypoint_statuses:
        prior_waypoint_status["status"] = "completed"
        current_waypoint_status["status"] = "executing"
        prior_waypoint_status = current_waypoint_status
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1.0, 5.0))

    prior_waypoint_status["status"] = "completed"

waypoints = [{"id": 1},{"id": 2},{"id": 3},{"id": 4},{"id": 5}]
waypoint_statuses = [{"id": waypoint["id"], "status": "pending"} for waypoint in waypoints]

update_waypoint_statuses(waypoint_statuses)
```

That will cycle through the waypoints on a 1 to 5 second randomized delay and update the status accordingly. If you want to see that happen, you can add in a couple of print/log statements:

```
def update_waypoint_statuses(waypoint_statuses):
    prior_waypoint_status = {"id": None, "status": None}

    for current_waypoint_status in waypoint_statuses:
        prior_waypoint_status["status"] = "completed"
        current_waypoint_status["status"] = "executing"
        prior_waypoint_status = current_waypoint_status
        print(waypoint_statuses, end="\r", flush=True)
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1.0, 5.0))

    prior_waypoint_status["status"] = "completed"
    print(waypoint_statuses, end="\r", flush=True)
```

If you want to do this while the main program does "something else", you can add in a `ThreadPoolExecutor()` and then you can print/log from you main line of code.

```
import concurrent.futures
import random
import time

def update_waypoint_statuses(waypoint_statuses):
    prior_waypoint_status = {"id": None, "status": None}

    for current_waypoint_status in waypoint_statuses:
        prior_waypoint_status["status"] = "completed"
        current_waypoint_status["status"] = "executing"
        prior_waypoint_status = current_waypoint_status
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1.0, 5.0))

    prior_waypoint_status["status"] = "completed"

waypoints = [{"id": 1},{"id": 2},{"id": 3},{"id": 4},{"id": 5}]
waypoint_statuses = [{"id": waypoint["id"], "status": "pending"} for waypoint in waypoints]

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future = executor.submit(update_waypoint_statuses, waypoint_statuses)

    while waypoint_statuses[-1]["status"] != "completed":
        print(waypoint_statuses, end="\r", flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print(waypoint_statuses, end="\r", flush=True)
    print("\n")
```

Depending on what "else" you might try to do with `waypoint_statuses`, you might also want to look into `threading.Lock()` but I don't think it is likely needed here. If your print gets mangled, it should sort itself out again on the next iteration.

Comment: Thank you for deep coding example, the expected result is not matching, let me explain 1st time if we have 3 id's then push `[{'id':1, 'status':'pending'}, {'id':2, 'status':'pending'}, {'id':3, 'status':'pending'}]` wait for 10 sec `[{'id':1, 'status':'executing'}, {'id':2, 'status':'pending'}, {'id':3, 'status':'pending'}]` wait for 10 sec `[{'id':1, 'status':'completed'}, {'id':2, 'status':'executing'}, {'id':3, 'status':'pending'}]` wait for 10 sec `[{'id':1, 'status':'completed'}, {'id':2, 'status':'completed'}, {'id':3, 'status':'executing'}]`

Comment: That is what this code does, only rather than every 10 seconds, it uses a random amount of time between 1 and 5 seconds. To make it always 10 seconds you would swap out `time.sleep(random.uniform(1.0, 5.0))` for `time.sleep(10)`